# Exercise 2 in section 2.4 of Kreyzig's functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Theorem: In a normed space $X$,  if $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set, then there exists a $c>0$ such that for every set of scalars $a_i$'s, $1\le i\le n$, the following holds:

$$\|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i\|\ge c\left (\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|\right)\tag 1$$

If $X=R^2$,where $R$ is the set of all reals. then an exercise asks to find the maximum c>0 such that $(1)$ holds.

If the norm is the Euclidean norm, then we have $|a|+|b|\le \sqrt 2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies \|(a,b)\|\ge \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \left(|a|+|b|\right)$. So the maximum $c$ is $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$. But since the exercise does not specify the norm, my question is: Can we find such maximum $c$ that works for every norm on $X$?

My another question is: If two norms say $p$ and $q$ are equivalent on finite dimensional space X and q comes from an inner product on X, then can we say that $p$ also comes from an inner product?

Edit: the second question has answer in negative as $\|.\|_1$ for example does not come from an inner product space.

Comment: Answer is NO for both.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Thanks for the comment. Is the exercise wrong then?

Comment: What is the largest possible c in (1) if $X = R^2$ and $x_1 = (1, 0),
x_2 = (0, I)$? This the phrasing of the exercise. One possibility is that by $R^2$ (bolded), they mean $R^2$ with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that is what they mean.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Thanks a lot. :)